# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. (Artech.Architecture.Common)

Tags: genexus

No estoy pudiendo iniciar Genexus 17u11, sale el siguiente error

```
Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. (Artech.Architecture.Common)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Artech.Architecture.Common.Packages.PackagesCatalog.get_CacheFileName()
   at Genexus.Win.GeneXusMain.Main(String[] args)
```

En la misma máquina tengo instalado versiones anteriores de Genexus y no tienen inconvenientes (Evo2, Evo3 y Genexus 15)
El SO es Windows 10 21h2 (19044.2130)

Comment: Parece un problema de instalación o requerimientos.
No me quedó claro si es al iniciar GX en si o al instalarlo.
Probaria apagando al soporte de NetFramework 3.5 a ver si te funciona, al menos  es lo que recomienda acá: https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=50345;;

Comment: Ocurre en ambas situaciones, al instalar y al iniciar, durante la instalación da el error, le das OK y continua hasta finalizar, luego al tratar de iniciar da el mismo error. Para mi no es un una opción desinstalar el soporte para el .NET Framework 3.5 porque también uso Genexus Evo2 y este necesita tener instalado el soporte para .NET Framework 3.5